# TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Add' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x' tf.cast is useless

Tags: python, tensorflow

today, I'm using TensorFlow to do some basic calculation, it suddenly has an error like below.

```
TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Add' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'.
```

I have tried to use tf.cast() to verify the type of the tensor, however, it seems to be useless which is based on that the types of  the four variables of 're', 're2', 're3' and 're4' are just float32 according to the output:

```
re1: Tensor("mul:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
re2: Tensor("mul_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
re3: Tensor("mul_4:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
re4: Tensor("mul_7:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

now, I don't know how to deal with the problem. anyone can give me a hand?
Any suggestion will be appreciated!!

here are some relative codes

```
re=(fc4[i][2]-fc4[i][0])*(fc4[i][3]-fc4[i][1])
re2=(bbox[i][2] - bbox[i][0]) * (bbox[i][3] - bbox[i][1])
re3=pro_x * (fc4[i][2] - fc4[i][0]) * pro_y * (fc4[i][3] - fc4[i][1])
re4=(pro_x*(fc4[i][2]-fc4[i][0])*pro_y*(fc4[i][3]-fc4[i][1]))  print("re1:",re)  
print("re2:",re2)
print("re3:",re3)  
print("re4:",re4)
overate=re4/(re+re2-re3)
```

the complete error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hp/anaconda3/envs/mypython37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 527, in _apply_op_helper
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "/home/hp/anaconda3/envs/mypython37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1224, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/home/hp/anaconda3/envs/mypython37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1018, in _TensorTensorConversionFunction
    (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("truediv_3:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/147/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/147/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/hp/Downloads/GOTURN-Tensorflow-master/got-10k/train/train2dup.py", line 215, in <module>
    aot=ao(tracknet.fc4,tracknet.bbox,BATCH_SIZE)
  File "/home/hp/Downloads/GOTURN-Tensorflow-master/got-10k/train/train2dup.py", line 168, in ao
    sum=tf.add(sum,overate)
  File "/home/hp/anaconda3/envs/mypython37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 387, in add
    "Add", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/home/hp/anaconda3/envs/mypython37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 563, in _apply_op_helper
    inferred_from[input_arg.type_attr]))
TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Add' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'.
```

Comment: From which line are you facing the error? & what is fc4 and bbox ?

Comment: provide your complete error log

Comment: @Kris thanks for your reading!! it is my fault the error exists on the line of "overate = re4/(re+re2-re3)"], and the fc4 and bbox are both tensors from a kind of cnn

Comment: @Alpha thanks!!!  Ok, wait a min!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify:

```py
sum=tf.add(sum,overate)
```

To:

```py
sum=tf.add(tf.cast(sum, overate.dtype),overate)
```